# Holomorphism of $f$ and $f^n$

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $f^3$ and $f^7$ holomorphic functions, I want to show that $f$ is holomorphic.

Can I say that if $f$ is not holomorphic then $f^3$ is not holomorphic which mean $f$ is must be holomorphic?

Comment: Is $f^n = f \cdot f \cdot \dots \cdot f$ or $f^n = f \circ f \circ \dots \circ f$?

Comment: To your last bit, no: consider ${}^3\sqrt{x}$. It most often doesn't work to ignore half the given information.

Comment: Even more drastic: take any function $f: \mathbb C \to \{ 1, \zeta, \zeta^2\}$, where $\zeta$ is a nontrivial third root of unity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As David pointed out, $f(z)=\frac{f^7(z)}{f^6(z)}$ is holomorphic at all points where $f^6(z)\neq0$. Using [Riemann's theorem on removable singularities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem) it's enough to show that $\lim_{z\to0}f(z)$ exists. Now, assume that $f^6(z_0)=0$. Since $f^6$ is holomorphic at $z_0$, you can write $f^6(z)=(z-z_0)^kg(z)$ where $g$ is holomorphic and $g(z_0)\neq0$. Also, $f^6(z_0)=0$ implies that $f^7(z_0)=0$, so you can write $f^7(z)=(z-z_0)^mh(z)$. Now consider $f^{42}$: it is holomorphic, as a product of holomorphic and hence $(z-z_0)^{7k}g(z)=(z-z_0)^{6m}h(z)$. Since the order of the zero at $z_0$ is constant, we have $7k=6m$, so $m>k$. Hence you can write $f(z)=(z-z_0)^{m-k}\frac{h(z)}{g(z)}$, and $g$ doesn't vanish at $z_0$, so the limit of $f(z)$ at $z_0$ exists (and is equal to $0$).

Comment: This is very nice:+1. However @David Wallace posted a solution before, which  Dennis's reasoning now makes complete. Since I'm the one who pointed out to David his  gap, I'd  like to ask him to undelete his answer and to just add a little pointer to Dennnis's answer  in an edit.